# Share a folder between my EC2 windows instance to my local PC

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a process that creates an EXCEL file on a local folder on my local PC.
I want to share this folder \ file with my EC2 instance on AWS.

FXs it's not an option because the costs are very high, file size is smaller than a 100MB.

any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "share"? Will the file be 'updated' in both locations, or is it just edited on your computer and 'read' on the EC2 instance? So, would a one-way copy work just as well? How often would the file be updated?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [secure copy](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/scp.htm) AKA: SCP.

SCP uses SSH (hence the name secure copy bit) because you are using a windows machine you'll need to make some changes to your machine first.

You should either look into WSL(windows subsystem for linux) or use native PowerShell, specifically [this pkg](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH/2.0.2)